# Woocommerce(wordpress) email type displaying 'plain/text' instead of 'text/html'

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, woocommerce, html-email

The Woocommerce email settings for all the orders are showing 'Plain text' as Email type, it should show HTML/Multipart too, but it is restricting or overriding to Plain Text. How can we have the options of HTML/Multipart.

I have added a function below to functions.php

```
function wps_set_content_type(){
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wps_set_content_type' );
```

but this does not works

Comment: In the dashboard, under **Woocommerce > Settings > Email**, you can change the different type of content for every notification (New order, New account, ...)

Answer (score 11):

It may be related to your server settings. To enable such feature, you have to install `php-gd`, `php-xml` and `php-xmlrpc` then restart your service.

Comment: @JLT I have these php packages running on the server and have the function added, but still no option to use html emails.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Presto did you restart PHP after installing those packages?

Comment: @JLT I restarted apache which I thought would do the trick.  I'll look into specifying PHP to restart.  I am running PHP 7 if that matters, thanks.