# can't change Email type in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, email, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to create custom design e-mails to my website (using HTML) but whenever I try the e-mail it shows plain text.

I went to woocommerce setting -> e-mail and I couldn't change the Email type. it is stuck on plain text. But when I search online I see that we have options we can choose from.

I appreciate if someone can guide me on how to make this feature works.

Notes: 
- I am using Amazon AWS ( I am not sure if there are permissions I need to give or do) 
- I am using WP-Mail-SMTP ( I tried to deactivate it but it didnt work) 
- website is www.howayte.com

Answer (score 1):

I have find the following post

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-email-type/

and I configured my setting based on the answer in the post below.

[Woocommerce(wordpress) email type displaying 'plain/text' instead of 'text/html'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139808/woocommercewordpress-email-type-displaying-plain-text-instead-of-text-html)

basically I accessed putty

wrote the following

sudo su

yum install php-xml
yum install php-gd
yum install php-xmlrpc

then restarted the service

service httpd restart

I also copied the template files from the "/plain" directory to the "/email" and it worked fine for me.

hope it help anyone who is in similar situation as I am