# How do I restore Woocommerce "email type" dropdown options?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, and during the transition Woocommerce reverted to plain text email format from HTML.

In the "Email Type" dropdown of Woocommerce > Settings, only Plain Text is available

I have checked my php modules and installed php-xmlrpc and php-gd as advised by [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824473/cant-change-email-type-in-woocommerce), then restarted php and Apache, but I can still only select plain text.

I would like to restore HTML email functionality: any ideas where I can look to fix this?

Comment: Answers are to go into the Answer section and not here in the Question.

Comment: Done, cheers Rob. I've been told the opposite before haha.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Hopefully this helps someone.

Somehow I have PHP7.2 and 7.3 installed on my server.

Using php -m showed the required modules (xml, xmlrpc, gd) as available in PHP7.3, but Wordpress was using 7.2

When I realised I got all the required modules on 7.2 (apt get php7.2-xml etc) then enabled them on that version (phpenmod -v 7.2 xml etc)

Now the html functionality is restored to WooCommerce emails